# Show static image on category if no category banner uploaded

Tags: magento-1.9, category, if

I have the following code that displays my ***category banner image***:

> ```
>           <?php
>             $_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
>             $_category  = Mage::registry('current_category');
>             $_imgHtml   = '';
>             if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
>                 $_imgHtml = '<p class="category-image"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'" alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" /></p>';
>                 $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
>             }
>             ?>
>
>           <?php if($_imgUrl): ?>
>           <?php echo $_imgHtml ?>
>           <?php endif; ?>
> ```

I'd like to adapt the code, so that ***if no category banner exists an alternative banner is displayed***. The alternative banner is stored in a static block called '***alternative_cat_banner***'.

Can anyone suggest an edit to the code above to achieve this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
<?php if($_imgUrl) { ?>
<!-- Category has Image uploaded -->
<?php echo $_imgHtml ?>
<?php }else{ ?>
<!-- Category has NO Image uploaded, show static block named alternative_cat_banner -->
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('alternative_cat_banner')->toHtml() ?>
<?php }?>
```